# React spinner while DOM is fetching

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Instead of adding a loading spinner to all components while fetching data, I want a general way of checking if DOM is fetching and then add/remove the loading spinner. Is this possible?

Comment: yes, this is possible. There are some packages which help you to achieve it  `https://www.basefactor.com/react-how-to-display-a-loading-indicator-on-fetch-calls` Check this

Comment: Create a HOC for that, pass your component to that HOC, based on fetching status it will either return spinner  or your component.you need to maintain fetching state inn your component and you should pass that state too to the HOC, to decide which component to return.